# Set multiple entries using react-app-rewired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-app-rewired, webpack-config

Below are some options from an open-webpack (not CRA) react project:

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    // ...
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js',
        'editor.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js',
        'yaml.worker': 'monaco-yaml/lib/esm/yaml.worker.js',
    },
    // ...
```

**How to implement similar configuration in `config-overrides.js` (using [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired))?**

```js
// config-overrides.js

module.exports = function override (config) {
    config.entry = // ???

    return config
}
```

---

###### My experience:

Simply set it to:

```js
config.entry = {
    main: './src/index.js',
    'editor.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js',
    'yaml.worker': 'monaco-yaml/lib/esm/yaml.worker.js',
}
```

doesn't work. It even causes issues in loading `index.js`!

Answer (score 1):

```js
config.optimization.runtimeChunk = 'single'
```

maybe help you ...

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk

---